# How can I add line breaks to the end of a macro?

Tags: macros, environments, best-practices

I want **to simplify the writing** of this content, which should appear tabulated.

I've written two macros to indent and colored `℣` and `℟`. And I want to avoid having to always write `\par` at the end of each line.

How could I make the `\par` to be inserted at the end of the macros ... and furthermore, at the end of the macro `\sr` to insert two line breaks.

Or ... **simplifying further**, could I insert the colored `℣` and `℟` from a macro or environment, **without having to type them in the text**?

This is my code:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openany,showtrims]{memoir}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{needspace}  
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\settrimmedsize{6in}{9in}{*}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}

\newfontfamily\fsfont{FreeSerif}
\newfontfamily\alterfont{FreeSans}

\newcommand{\txtred}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand{\h}{\hspace{5mm}}
\newcommand{\hl}{\hspace{10mm}}
\newcommand{\sv}{\txtred}
\newcommand{\sr}{\txtred}

\newenvironment{readbody}{%
    \alterfont
}%

\begin{document}
    \mainmatter
    \begin{readbody}
        \sv ℣.  \h Señor, enséñame tus caminos,\par
                \hl instrúyeme en tus sendas: \par
                \hl haz que camine con lealtad;\par
                \hl enséñame, porque tú eres mi Dios y Salvador. \sr ℟.\par \par 
                %Need two lines skip here
        \sv ℣.  \h Recuerda, Señor, que tu ternura\par
                \hl y tu misericordia son eternas;\par
                \hl acuérdate de mí con misericordia,\par
                \hl por tu bondad, Señor. \sr ℟.\par \par                        
                %Need two lines skip here
        \sv ℣.  \h El Señor es bueno y es recto,\par
                \hl enseña el camino a los pecadores;\par
                \hl hace caminar a los humilles con rectitud,\par
                \hl enseña su camino a los humildes. \sr ℟.
    \end{readbody}  
\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image]

I want simplify, writing this:

```
\begin{readbody}
    \sv ℣.  \h Señor, enséñame tus caminos,
            \hl instrúyeme en tus sendas: 
            \hl haz que camine con lealtad;
            \hl enséñame, porque tú eres mi Dios y Salvador. \sr ℟.
    \sv ℣.  \h Recuerda, Señor, que tu ternura
            \hl y tu misericordia son eternas;
            \hl acuérdate de mí con misericordia,
            \hl por tu bondad, Señor. \sr ℟.
    \sv ℣.  \h El Señor es bueno y es recto,
            \hl enseña el camino a los pecadores;
            \hl hace caminar a los humilles con rectitud,
            \hl enseña su camino a los humildes. \sr ℟.
\end{readbody}
```

And giving this:

[image]

I am starting with LaTeX. So I'm open to suggestions for better ways to do this, keeping in mind that one of my goals in this particular case is **to simplify the writing**.

Comment: Is the 5mm and 10mm spacing here  required or is the intention that the left edge of the text is all aligned?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added 5mm and 10mm arbitrarily, but the intention is for the text to appear aligned.

Comment: currently it appears disturbingly unaligned, which is why I asked:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

I have used `\obeylines` and `\everypar` to add the items automatically, note that your environment definition was missing the second argument with the end code.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openany,showtrims]{memoir}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
% \usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{needspace}  
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\settrimmedsize{6in}{9in}{*}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}

\newfontfamily\fsfont{FreeSerif}
\newfontfamily\alterfont{FreeSans}

\newcommand{\txtred}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand{\sv}{\txtred}
\newcommand{\sr}{\txtred}

\makeatletter
\catcode13\active %
\newenvironment{readbody}{%
    \alterfont%
    \setlength\parskip{\bigskipamount}%
    \setlength\parindent{0pt}%
    \setlength\leftskip{10mm}%
    \catcode13\active %
    \def^^M{\@ifnextchar^^M{\par}{\@ifnextchar\end{\ifhmode\par\fi}{\ifhmode\\\fi}}}%
    \def\par{~\sr ℟.\endgraf}%
    \everypar{\makebox[0pt]{\sv ℣.\qquad}}%
}{}%
\catcode13=5 %
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \mainmatter
    \begin{readbody}
         Señor, enséñame tus caminos,
         instrúyeme en tus sendas: 
         haz que camine con lealtad;
         enséñame, porque tú eres mi Dios y Salvador.

          Recuerda, Señor, que tu ternura
          y tu misericordia son eternas;
          acuérdate de mí con misericordia,
          por tu bondad, Señor.

          El Señor es bueno y es recto,
          enseña el camino a los pecadores;
          hace caminar a los humilles con rectitud,
          enseña su camino a los humildes.

    \end{readbody}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Even simpler! I am loving the way things can be simplified with LaTeX! Many thanks David!

Comment: I have a question regarding your code: If I implement your solution **I would no longer need the macros `sv` and `sr` in context**. I have tried to change this: `~\sr ℟.\endgraf` for this **`~\txtred ℟.\endgraf`** and this `\sv ℣.\qquad` for this **`\txtred ℣.\qquad`** and it works apparently. Will there be a problem if I leave it like this?

Comment: @A.Cedano no that's fine. The one bad part of this code is that it requires a blank line at the end before the `\end{..}` that would be fixable but a bit tricky so not tonight.

Comment: Ok, I see. May I ask about this maybe tomorrow in a new question?

Comment: @A.Cedano not worth a new question, I may add something here  later (well of course you are free to ask any question you want:-)

Comment: @A.Cedano fixed:-)

Comment: It works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This is a solution that can be right for you. I changed your definition of `\sv` and `\rv` and redefined the `readbody` environment.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openany,showtrims]{memoir}
\settrimmedsize{6in}{9in}{*}
\usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{FreeSerif}
  \newfontfamily\fsfont{FreeSerif}
  \newfontfamily\alterfont{FreeSans}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{xcolor}  

\newcommand{\sv}{\item\textcolor{red}{℣}.\quad}
\newcommand{\sr}{\textcolor{red}{℟}.\medskip}

\newenvironment{readbody}{\list{}{
  \itemindent=-1cm
  \leftmargin=1cm
  \parsep=0pt}
  \obeylines\alterfont}{\endlist}

\begin{document}
\begin{readbody}
\sv Señor, enséñame tus caminos,
    instrúyeme en tus sendas: 
    haz que camine con lealtad;
    enséñame, porque tú eres mi Dios y Salvador. \sr

\sv Recuerda, Señor, que tu ternura
    y tu misericordia son eternas;
    acuérdate de mí con misericordia,
    por tu bondad, Señor. \sr                        

\sv El Señor es bueno y es recto,
    enseña el camino a los pecadores;
    hace caminar a los humilles con rectitud,
    enseña su camino a los humildes. \sr
\end{readbody}

\end{document}
```